# Apply formatting to all tables in a MS Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, microsoft-word-2013

Is it possible to apply formatting to all tables in a single document without doing it one by one?

Comment: Thanks! I've never written a macro for Word, but I've recently managed to learn some VB for Access and Excel, so I should be able to figure it out.

Comment: If you have any problems creating the macro just read the tutorial I've linked to in my answer.